# Windows Azure Architecture Guide – Part 2 – Code Samples

Tags: visual-studio-2012, converters

I download the package from this url:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27878
I have Visual Studio 2012 and i would like to open the sln.
Visual Studio 2012 convert the sln 2010 to 2012 but the project is not compatible.

Have you the same project for VS 2012 ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The download you point to is in fact compatible with VS2012, however you have to first make sure to install the Windows Azure SDK for .NET from :

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=254364

This includes the bits needed for VS2012 to understand the project types contained in the samples.

More info about the Azure SDK for .NET can be found here:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35448

Also, check the release notes in the extracted folder.  It details the other requirements such as SQL Server, ASP.NET MVC, etc.